# Get the list of Subsidiary netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Can anyone help me on how to get the list of a particular subsidiary in netsuite, when I click the radio button of subsidiary?

The form is created by using suitelets.
I need to change the value of the drop down by using some client script

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a comma separated list of the first 20 subsidiaries.

I tested the script out in the NetSuite debugger.

```
var rec = '';
var theSubsidiaries;
var maxRecs = 20;

// SEARCH FOR SUBSIDIARY RECORDS
var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord( 'subsidiary', null, null, null );

// LOOP THROUGH THE SUBSIDIARIES (UP TO 20 RECS)
for ( var i = 0; i < Math.min( maxRecs, searchResults.length ); i++)
{

    // LOAD THE SUBSIDIARY RECORD
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord(searchResults[i].getRecordType(),searchResults[i].getId() );

    // CONCATENATE VALUES (SEE NETSUITE REC BROWSER FIELD NAMES)
    rec = rec + record.getId() + ' - ' + record.getFieldValue('name');

    // CONCATENATE A COMMA IF NOT LAST RECORD
    if (i < Math.min( maxRecs, searchResults.length ))
    {
        rec = rec + ', ';
    }
}

// ASSIGN VALUES TO A NEW VARIABLE
theSubsidiaries = rec;
```